# Spatial join (Points to Polygons) joining points that do not fall inside polygons to attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I am using ArcMap 10.6.1 and am having trouble with a spatial join. I have created 250km buffer polygons around some of my sampled data points and I am now trying to join some modelled data to those polygons to give me the average, min, max, and deviation of the data from that global model.

For some of my polygons, the join works normally but for others Arc is sampling points nowhere near the polygon or just not sampling the data inside the polygon at all rendering zeros '0' in the data columns after joining.

Here are the points inside the polygons and their data:

[image: Data table for points inside polygon]

and here is the output of that polygon:

[image: Data table for polygon itself]

As you can see the data are coming out as zero when there are usable data within the polygon.

These are the join parameters I am using:

[image: join parameters]

Why this might be happening?

Comment: Are the layers used in the spatial join different coordinate systems?

Comment: Yes they are all in the GCS_WGS_1984 system

Comment: Can you share some sample data via google drive/dropbox?

Comment: I just tried this and got Nulls, not 0s, when there was no intersection. You could try a spatial select to just get the matches before doing this step. You should not have to, but who knows.